# Bash aliases not working over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

My Bash aliases are not working over ssh, for example:

```
$ ssh remote_name ll dir_name
bash: ll: command not found
```

The Bash man page says:

```
Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive,
unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt...
```

So I added `shopt -s expand_aliases` at the top of my `~/.bashrc` file in both the local and remote `.bashrc` files (since I wasn't sure which was needed - remote right??).

I restarted the local Bash and tried `ssh remote_name ll dir_name` again, unfortunately I still got the same error `bash: ll: command not found`.

Can anyone explain what I should do to get this working please?

Just in case my Bash versions are:

```
Local Bash:
$ bash --version 
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Remote Bash:
$ bash --version 
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` is read by an non-login, interactive session of `bash`, not by non-interactive sessions.

`ssh remote some_command` is running `some_command` in an non-interactive session of `bash`, hence the remote `~/.bashrc` is not being read (and of course reading the local one is out of question).

Precisely, non-interactive session of `bash` can read the file defined by the environment variable `BASH_ENV` or `ENV` (if set).

If you want to stick with the aliases, open the shell in interactive mode too:

```
ssh remote bash -ic 'll'
```

---

Also note that, aliases are standalone, they don't take any argument like you are providing a directory name. You need to use functions to have arguments as inputs. A similar function definition would be:

```
ll_f () { ls -al --color=auto "$@" ;}
```

Now you can do:

```
ll_f /dir_name
```

Comment: Thanks, the alias itself works (`ll` gives me the `-l` listing) but when I add a directory name, `ssh remote bash -ic 'll dir_name'`, it gives me just the full listing of `~/` and not of `dir_name`.

Comment: @mattst Check my edits

Comment: Thanks, `ssh remote ll_f dir_name` works a treat.

Comment: NOTE: `.bashrc` _may_ be read by non-interactive sessions.  `$ head -1 .bashrc
echo RUNNING BASHRC
$ ssh localhost echo hello
RUNNING BASHRC
hello
`

Comment: My ssh non-interactive session reads `.bashrc` but does not respect aliases.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way (in `~/.bashrc`):

```
function bassh() {
    local host=${1:?'arg #1 missing: remote host'}
    shift
    local command="$@"
    local usage="bassh REMOTE_HOST COMMAND"

    [ "$command" ] || {
        echo -e >&2 "[error] no command provided\nUsage: ${usage}"
        return 1
    }

    ssh ${host} -t bash -ic "'${command}'"
}
```

Note the `-t` option to ssh which forces pseudo-terminal allocation, thus avoiding related warnings.

Then you call it simply:

```
$ bassh REMOTE_HOST ll
```

Answer (score -2):

use

```
 #!/bin/bash -l
```

it resolved the issue

Comment: Are you sure it resolved the issue described by the OP?  `-l` makes `bash` act like a login shell, which means it *won't* read `.bashrc`.