# Run an alias over ssh that runs another alias via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to run an alias over ssh that runs another alias via ssh. Is this possible?

I was looking at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303313/bash-aliases-not-working-over-ssh) question about running aliases over ssh and I got this so far:

```
ssh develop -t /bin/bash -ic "gotoserver"
```

`gotoserver` is an alias that runs:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user 10.10.10.10
```

This all works and I end up to `10.10.10.10`. But I'm looking to run another alias inside `10.10.10.10` so I tried this:

```
ssh develop -t /bin/bash -ic "gotoserver -t /bin/bash -ic 'loaddocker'"
```

But it's not working. It seems to only recognize until `gotoserver`.
I still end up at `10.10.10.10` but the rest of the command (`-t /bin/bash -ic 'loaddocker'`) seems to be ignored.

But if I go inside `develop` and run:

```
gotoserver -t /bin/bash -ic 'loaddocker'
```

It works and `loaddocker` is executed.

What am I doing wrong? And can I do this another way without changing anything in `develop` and `10.10.10.10`?

Comment: Can you say something about what is actually happening when you try to run that command that you say does not work? Like, what does it actually end up doing? Any error messages? Why do you quote `loaddocker`?

Comment: Yes I described it: `It seems to only recognize until gotoserver` meaning I still end up at `10.10.10.10` but the rest of the command seems to be ignored. I will update my question

Comment: Is there any reason you favor `ssh develop` to then `ssh smthingelse` instead of just using a jump?

Comment: `develop` serves like a  bastion so I need to get through it first. The only way to get to `smthingelse` is through `develop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*use functions insteed of aliases!*

```
function fnchunk () {
    echo -n function\ ;
    typeset -f ${@}
}

function requote () 
{ 
    if (($#)); then
        local re savedq='#...___+++...#' dblquote='"' singlequote="'" escapedsinglequote="\'" escapeddblquote='\"';
        re="$(printf "${savedq}%s${savedq} " "${@}")";
        re="${re//${dblquote}/${escapeddblquote}}";
        echo "${re//${savedq}/${dblquote}}";
    fi
}

function loadDockerWrapper(){
    echo loaddocker # call loadDocker script not alias
    # or if it was an alias turn it into function here
}

function gotoserver(){
    /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user 10.10.10.10 -tq "$(fnchunk fnchunk requote gotoserver loadDockerWrapper)" ";" $(requote "${@}")
}

function devCmd(){
    /usr/bin/ssh -tq develop "$(fnchunk fnchunk requote gotoserver loadDockerWrapper)" ";" $(requote "${@}")
}

devCmd gotoserver loadDockerWrapper
```

Comment: The aliases are dynamically generated, for example the ip in `gotoserver` can change, and the docker container id for `loaddocker` can change as well so I was looking for an approach to always call the alias. For now I have no control of changing those alias in the remote to functions. But I will try this and see if it works. Thank you!

Comment: It works. Can you explain what `fnchunk` and `requote` is doing? Using this backbone, is it not possible to execute aliases instead?

Comment: requote re-quotes your arguments in case you give more args containning spaces,  fnchunk gives you the function's body chunk (like func.toString() in js).

Answer (score 1):

`gotoserver` should contain something like `$@` as for all `gotoserver` arguments. You can use it this way:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user 10.10.10.10 $@
```

where `$@` will be all arguments passed to gotoserver and for `ssh` it will be a command to issue on 10.10.10.10.

Also, you can issue few commands one after another by separating them with `;`, for example:

```
echo a ; echo b
```